# How to Find the Middle Character(s) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, syntax, syntax-error

I'm trying to write a method in Ruby that:

1. if the string length is even numbers it will return the middle two characters and,
2. if the string length is odd it will return only the middle character

i put together this code, but it is not working:

```
def the_middle(s)
   if s.length % 2 == 0
      return s.index(string.length/2-1) && s.index(string.length/2)
   else
      return s.index(string.length/2).round 
   end
end
```

I think the problem is in the syntax, not the logic, and I was hoping someone could identify where the syntax error might be.

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You mention that your code doesn't work, but you don't tell us what that means. What do you expect to happen when you run the code, and why is that the correct behavior? What happens instead and why is that wrong? What are the *precise* errors you are getting? Please give sample inputs and outputs of what *should* happen as well as sample inputs and sample outputs of what *actually* happens. Show us how you call the method you defined. Also, you mention syntax errors as well. Again, what are the *precise* error messages, where is the syntax error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you have both syntax errors and logic (semantic) errors in that code.

First of all it seems you have misunderstood how the `index` method on string works. It does not return the character at the given index but the index of a given substring or regex as can be seen in the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-index):

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the given substring or pattern (regexp) in str.

You're also using the wrong operator to concatenate the two middle characters when the string length is even. `&&` is the *logical and* operator. It's usually used for conditions and not assigments - for example in an if statement `if s.length.even? && s.length > 2`. The operator you want to use is `+` which concatenates strings.

Finally, you're using `string.length` but `string` is not defined anywhere. What you mean is probably `s.length` (the input parameter).

The correct solution would be more like the following:

```
def the_middle(s)
   if s.length.even?
      return s[s.length/2-1] + s[s.length/2]
   else
      return s[s.length/2]
   end
end
```

I have taken the liberty to replace `s.length % 2 == 0` with `s.length.even?` as it's more intention revealing and really the ruby way of finding out whether an integer is even or odd.

Comment: thank you so much for your help! that worked. so if i want to find the index position of a string in the future, the technique is just, "string"[ index position ]

Comment: Glad to help. However, that depends on what you mean by *index position*? `str[pos]` returns the element at `pos` in `str` while `str.index(x)` returns the *index* of the first occurence of `x` in `str`. Do you see the difference? If you're ever in doubt the [Ruby documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html) contains excellent examples that usually enlightens the situation. Look in the *methods* section to the left.

Comment: yeah i do. the first is from the string the second is the index position itself.

Comment: Exactly. Good luck in your Ruby adventures. It's a really fun and productive language once you get used to it.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this without a conditional using `String#[]`.

Using a range with a negative end:

```
def the_middle(s)
  i = (s.length - 1) / 2
  s[i..-i.succ]
end
```

Or start and length:

```
def the_middle(s)
  a, b = (s.length - 1).divmod(2)
  s[a, b + 1]
end
```

Both return the same results:

```
   the_middle("a")     #=> "a"
  the_middle("aba")    #=> "b"
 the_middle("abcba")   #=> "c"
the_middle("abcdcda")  #=> "d"
#              ^

  the_middle("abba")   #=> "bb"
 the_middle("abccba")  #=> "cc"
the_middle("abcddcda") #=> "dd"
#              ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def get_middle(s)
  x = (s.length/2) 
  s.length.even? ? s[x-1..x] : s[x]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since olerass already answered your doubt about the syntax, i will suggest you a less verbose solution for the question in the title:

```
def the_middle(s)
  return s[s.length/2] if s.length.odd?
  s[s.length/2-1] + s[s.length/2]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Same answer the syntax is just consolidated.
2. **Format** (logic result) ? ( if true this is the result) : (if false this is the result)

   ```
   def get_middle(s)
      num = s.length
      num.even? ? ( s[num/2-1] + s[num/2]) : (s[num/2])
   end
   ```